# Instead of multiple if statements Java date

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a better way to write this instead of writing multiple if statements?

I'm parsing through a document to find the instances of date and incrementing the int if an instance occurs.

```
public class OrganisingData {

    static int jan16=0;
    static int feb16=0;
    static int mar16=0;//... static int dec18

    public static void Months(String dates) {
        if (dates.substring(2, 4).equals("16") && 
            dates.substring(5,7).equals("01")) {
            jan16++;
        }
        if (dates.substring(2, 4).equals("16") && 
            dates.substring(5,7).equals("02")) {
            feb16++;...
        }
        if (dates.substring(2, 4).equals("18") &&
            dates.substring(5,7).equals("12")) {
            dec18++;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to build a bar chart and jan16 feb16 etc represent the month and the year and each time i find an insistence of that date (eg. 2016-01-15) i would increment jan16. so instead of writing multiple if statements for each month + year (total of 32 if statements)is there a better way to write this?

Comment: If the code is working, this question may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `String a = dates.substring(2, 4), b = dates.substring(5,7);` and then use `a` and `b` instead?

Comment: You might want to use an array for your jan16, feb16, march16 … variables. Then you could use a for loop and convert your int iterator to a String and compare it with your input String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using appropriate data structures, you can greatly reduce this code.
The idea is to have a data structure that for each year you're interested in, holds an array of ints: one for each month.

Then, converting the substrings from the `dates` String to numbers, you can use those numbers to index the data structure.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

private static Map<Integer, int[]> years = new HashMap<>();
private static String[] monthNames = new String[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

static {
    for(int year = 16; year <= 18; year++) {
        years.put(year, new int[12]);
    }
}

public static void months(String dates) { // method names should start with lower case
    int year = Integer.parseInt(dates.substring(2, 4));
    int month = Integer.parseInt(dates.substring(5, 7)) - 1; // date String is one-based, array-index is zero-based
    years.get(year)[month]++;
}

public static void print() {
    for(int year = 16; year <= 18; year++) {
        int[] monthCounts = years.get(year);
        for(int month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
            System.out.println(monthNames[month] + " " + year + ": " + monthCounts[month]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the code in action [here](https://tio.run/##nZNLj9owEIDPya8Y5ZQoIUtQ96GGrlS1qtqV2B44Ig6GuGAa7Mh2IBTx29nxg126bNWqBGnGnhn7m4dXZEN6oqF8Vf08Htm6EVLDCjfzVrM6H5GmDC92vxK1tJawaWc1m8O8JkrBiDAO@zAMGsk2RFNQmmi0ouvwG9d0QWUGjOvJ9B52lEgFH4DTLfjjhvdxUl4Ej7VkfDGZwlpwvXwka3oKe7bsowfCowyiL3RmxIhIIz420q12Rjy03Ina2tqFEWPaGPF9ro14FBsjPtN5dMDcAk@wDwF/QfBDyBjpLToiFDelU4eo3zk9TZOTuw1xaeZNq2OjZZbbVKAYTDFXd@4hxD/m7UrpL90IVrmUVewShQqrovB8uLqCNdVLUQG35VBL0daVicQubZleQi22VMKcKBo6jjNu34m8QTKKi9iem6t2puw98SCDd4mj85GW419CrzO4TRLoQVEaSmP2bQKmQHDamyFTlQGRkux6jFe0M5ZfVApnCs/rtqCubsnEEkzTtPxjrXBsECj5v265EDuaLtlPouXaDNorkPLM/XTDqTr90qtDKAZe//0KFxeMd0rTdS5anVvqmscvw@1ThRQi/FIHjYv3dnUG5x1fkAIzSn8dKXyj8fPLIXJhJioMAj9qUdcVN11/EJmXeL552/WvLzbf9LzrisJt@pbYnh2Oxyc).

Answer (score 3):

Basically a mix of what @John T and @Zachary said, but with proper syntax and type conversion.

```
// [Years] and [Months], where [0][0] is jan 2000. May need to adjust for previous years.
int[][] days = new int[30][12];

void month(String dates) {
    int year = Integer.parseInt(dates.substring(2, 4)); 
    int month = Integer.parseInt(dates.substring(5,7)) - 1;

    days[year][month]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to reduce the clunky logic, though this wouldn't necessarily condense greatly. You will either need to use [Strings with the Switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) or convert the day/month values to an integer.

```
String day = dates.substring(2, 4);
String month = dates.substring(5, 7);

switch (month) {
    case "01" : {
        if (day.equals("16"))
            jan16++;
        break;
    }
}
```

If there is some pattern behind what you are wanting to do, there may be a better solution. For example, the following would count 16th of each month

```
int count[] = new int[12];
  ...
int day = Integer.parseInt(dates.substring(2, 4));
int month = Integer.parseInt(dates.substring(5, 7));


if (day == 16)
    count[month - 1]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

## `YearMonth`

Apparently you want to track year-month values. There's a class for that, named, well, [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). Find this class in the *java.time* package that supplants the terribly troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

## `MonthDay`

Or maybe you are shooting for month-day values; your Question is convoluted so I am not sure of your goal. But if this is your goal, again, there’s a class for that: [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).

## `Month`

Or maybe you want just the month regardless of year or day-of-month, in which case you can use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) class.

## `LocalDate`

If your inputs strings represent a year and month and day-of-month, parse as a `LocalDate`. This class has no time-of-day and no time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016-01-15" ) ;
```

Extract a `YearMonth`, `MonthDay`, or `Month`.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Create a collection. Perhaps you want to keep all a distinct set of the `LocalDate` objects in a particular year-month. If so, make a `Map` where each `YearMonth` object owns a `Set` of `LocalDate` objects.

```
Map < YearMonth, Set < LocalDate > > map = new HashMap <>();
```

As you process each input date, check to see if the map has a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) yet created for the particular `YearMonth` of the input. If not, instantiate a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). The `TreeSet` class is a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), meaning it maintains a sorted order as you add values.

```
Set < LocalDate > set = map.get( ym );
if ( null == set ) {
    set = new TreeSet <>(); // A `TreeSet` is a `SortedSet`, maintains a sorted order. You may or may not need this behavior.
    map.put( ym , set );
}
```

With a `Set` in hand, add your `LocalDate`.

```
set.add( ld );
```

After processing, you can get a collection of the `YearMonth` keys from your `Map`. And for each of those, you can retrieve the `Set` it owns, and get a count of the elements contained.

### Lamba & Streams

For shorter code, you might be able to use Lambda syntax & Streams with [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)). I've seen this kind of code but have not yet tried it.

```
map.computeIfAbsent( key , k -> new TreeSet< LocalDate >() ).add( ld ) ;
```

### Count only

If you want only the count, and don't care about the `LocalDate` values, replace `Set` as the “value” or you `Map` with a `Integer` object. Instead of retrieving the `Set` and adding to it, retrieve the `Integer` and increment it by adding one. Personally, in this kind of situation I find it best to collect the `LocalDate` values to be examined for debugging/testing and/or for further use in other business logic.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

Loop through your document with this:

```
// 18 years(more needed?), 12 months
String[][] yearsAndMonths = new String[18][12];  

yearsAndMonths[dates.substring(5,7)][dates.substring(2, 4)]++;
```

Then print the results.

I'm not a java expert. Code just provided to give you the logic.

Comment: You can't use a String to index an array.

Comment: also, I just noticed, you are declaring an array of `Strings` – you can't use the `++` operator like you would on an int.

Comment: The string array would also default everything to `null`. If you could use `++`, it would throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: The code was given to present the logic. I'm sure it can be adjusted to a proper way to do it in Java.

Comment: That's no excuse to present code that is completely wrong. Please, either edit your post so the code contains no errors, or delete it.

Comment: @O.O.Balance I gave the logic that answered the question "Is there a better way to write this instead of writing manipulate(multiple) if statements?". I see others built on it to give a complete solution. With your reasoning there would be very few answers on SO. Most of them lack code, are incomplete or have errors, including yours. Nevertheless, they're helpful.

Comment: If you've found an error in my answer, please do tell me about it so I can fix it.

Comment: Turns out I had indeed missed a `;` in my answer. I have added a link so you can see it compile and run, I believe there are no more errors. If you still think there is something wrong with my answer, please let me know.

Comment: Regarding my "reasoning": I strive to provide answers that are correct. But, what's more, I try to help both the OP and any future readers that may stumble upon the question; to that end I will often edit my answers after posting them. So when I see an answer that is not as helpful as it can be, I may comment on it. I do not mean any offense, please don't be insulted – I merely want to make sure your answer will help people, which is why we're here. As a positive side-effect to you, an improved answer is more likely to attract upvotes (and keep downvotes away).

Comment: When I see an answer that contains errors however, I think the case for editing is much stronger: We don't want to mislead our readers or teach them bad habits. I can imagine your code being copy-pasted by someone who then gets slapped in the face with multiple compile-time errors. They may even ask a question about it here – causing people to essentially waste their time dealing with it. You may want to read this blog post by our esteemed Jon Skeet: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/

Comment: @O.O.Balance I'm happy you got it working correctly. I will avoid posting both solutions and comments when I'm not able to provide a full answer. I have a family to support that is much more important. Personally I like any help in the right direction when I'm stuck, but I guess that's just me. :)